# Preventing a Query Rule from operating until user hits enter in search results web part

Tags: javascript, search, csom

I would like to implement Mikael Svenson and Elio Struyf's approach in the following excerpt below in order to intercept a query rule from firing as the webpage loads.  But how do I even begin this process of adding code to do as he suggests?  What should I begin to study in order to learn more about this process?

https://github.com/SPCSR/HelperFunctions/tree/master/SPO-Search-Improvements

```
 "Technical details: In order to modify a SharePoint search query before it's 
 being executed you need to hook in your logic at the right stage in the 
 pages JavaScript lifecycle. This is achieved with the following code snippet:

 [code]

 ExecuteOrDelayUntilBodyLoaded is first in the life cycle, and ensures our 
 script runs before the SharePoint search web parts. Then we override the 
 single and multi-query functions which allows us to stop the query cycle 
 and perform any asynchronous loading operation before the query continues."
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to prevent the rule from firing when {searchterms} is empty (i.e. When the page first loads and the search box is blank), wrap the rule with '{?' and '}'.

Comment: thanks for your answer.  However, do you have any advice on the question at hand here?  I am struggling with the process of implementing the fix proposed above.    I have attempted the method of wrapping my query in curly brackets and the question mark, but that has not solved my dilemma.  One query rule is on, and my search results web part is auto-populating before any terms are entered.

Comment: if i can figure out how "to hook in [my] logic at the right stage in the 
 pages JavaScript lifecycle" then I will be on my way. Particularly where to hook in my logic.  Is this something that takes place in the master page, or a display template?

Comment: Where is your query rule defined?

Comment: this query rule is defined on a site level.

Comment: Are you wrapping the entire rule or just {searchterms}?  You can test this when editing the query rule with the Test Query button.  If you don't enter anything into the search terms box and no results come back, then you know it's working (at least from the base web parts/search engine perspective).

Comment: You are goping to laugh and understand why my search results are autopoulating when you see how my query rule is changing my query>>>

{? {searchboxquery} XRANK(cb=0) {subjectTerms) XRANK(cb=5000) {actionTerms}}

Comment: using XRANK has allowed me to prevent the query from breaking when a user enters some random query (ex: massive email dinosaur rampage).  the search is still recognizing the word "email." but now I need a workaround for preventing the results from autopopulating, while still allowing users to type in what ever the heck they want without killing the query.